# Spring-Data-Envers repository fails to inject

Tags: spring-data

In my spring context I've the following:

```
<jpa:repositories base-package="x.y.service.springDataJpa"/>  
<jpa:repositories base-package="x.y.service.springDataEnvers"
                  factory-class="org.springframework.data.envers.repository.support.EnversRevisionRepositoryFactoryBean" />
```

This should pick up my normal spring-data-jpa repositories and my spring-data-envers repository.

But when executing this junit testclass:

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration(classes = {ApplicationTestContext.class, OrmContext.class, DatasourceContext.class})
@ActiveProfiles(profiles = "LOCAL")
@Transactional
public class StoreAndRetrieveRevisionTest {

    @Inject
    private ServiceRepository serviceRepository;

    @Inject
    private ServiceRevisionRepository serviceRevisionRepository;
```

(The ApplicationTestContext.class loads the xml config).

It fails to inject the revisionrepository bean:

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'x.y.server.springDataJpa.hibernateenvers.StoreAndRetrieveRevisionTest': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: private x.y.service.springDataEnvers.ServiceRevisionRepository x.y.server.springDataJpa.hibernateenvers.StoreAndRetrieveRevisionTest.serviceRevisionRepository; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type [x.y.service.springDataEnvers.ServiceRevisionRepository] found for dependency: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations: {@javax.inject.Inject()}
```

What am I missing here?
The spring-data-envers documentation is rather sparse..

Answer (score 0):

Please check if you have your entity class properly annotated with @Entity and @Table annotation. If not your repository bean will not get properly initialized and you will not be able to use it.